# Is there any way i can check if the user is not active since x months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I'm using rails 6 and devise for authentication. I know it can be done with session but dont know how. I will be thankful for your kind response.

Comment: In devise there is an attribute `last_sign_in_at `. Use that. check if `last_sign_in_at ` < 6.months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by active you mean that a user hasn't signed in for x months. Then you can check `last_sign_in_at` column in `users` table. The column should be created by Devise.

```
months = 6 # Put your value here
if user.last_sign_in_at? && user.current_sign_in_at.blank?
  user.last_sign_in_at < Time.now.months_ago(months)
end
```

If a user has never been signed in you can check `created_at` field in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

first implement this method in your user model:

```
def active_in_last_6_months?
  last_sign_in_at < 6.months.ago
end
```

then on your controller/view:

```
current_user.active_in_last_6_months?
```

Comment: I got the devise default behaviour. Thanks for your response.